# Activate Trigger From Lightning Component

Tags: apex, trigger, lightning, ui, component

I am trying to create a lightning component that allows user to select an object and activate a trigger according to the object selected, similar to process builder but I’m trying to integrate this functionality to an app so I was wondering if this is possible.

Answer (score 2):

Apex trigger is the code which is directly attached to database and can be invoked ONLY by [Apex DML Operations](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dml_section.htm). You may use Apex class as handler/helper classes which when invoked from trigger will have trigger context variables but when you try to invoke same handler/helper classes from outside like lightning component/process builder, you will not have any scope of trigger context variables.,

Comment: He probably meant creating dynamic triggers..

Answer (score 0):

Triggers are basically metadata, that means in order to active a trigger you have to do a deployment.

Various app exchange packages do this, one notable example being [DRLS](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N3000000B45gWEAR), they use Apex [metadata API wrapper](https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi) to dynamically deploy code on its own org.

Comment: This was very helpful, thanks.